# How to find the second word in a string

Tags: c#, winforms

When I run this code, it's purpose is to obtain the first, second, and third word in a 3 word sentence only and have each of those words display in a text box.  The sentence I use is 'kerry tells stories', look at pic to see what I mean,

The problem however, is that when i run it, the third word is 'stori', what happened to 'es' making 'stories'

[image]

```
var tbt = textBox.Text;
var firstWord = tbt.Substring(0, tbt.IndexOf(" "));

var indexword = tbt.IndexOf(" "); 
var indexnumber = indexword +1; 
string myString = indexnumber.ToString();   

var secondWord = tbt.Substring(indexnumber, tbt.IndexOf(" "));
var indexword2 = tbt.IndexOf(" ", indexnumber);

var indexnumber2 = indexword2 + 1; 
string myString2 = indexnumber2.ToString();


var thirdWord = tbt.Substring(indexnumber2, tbt.IndexOf(" "));
var indexword3 = tbt.IndexOf(" ", indexnumber2);
var indexnumber3 = indexword3 + 1; 
string mystring3 = indexnumber3.ToString();


textBox6.Text = firstWord;
textBox7.Text = secondWord;
textBox8.Text = thirdWord;
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: `string.Split` would make this much easier, you should give that a google.

Comment: Try to learn how to debug using breakpoints. See what the values are used in your code and compare that to what you expected. That should help you figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Note that the word 'word' is not really defined. The best solution would involve a RegEx with a 'word separator'. For strictly space separated sentences the proposed solutions will work. If more than one space may be there look into the SplitOptions! For learning about IndexOf do use the debugger!!

Comment: In your current code, the problem is you're getting `tbt.IndexOf(" ")` everywhere, it only looks for first `space` and it is at index `5`. It means you are giving it length of `5` every time.

Comment: Regex.Matches(tbl, @"\S+") is a better way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try splitting the sentence via `String.Split()` method:

```
string test = "kelly tell stories";
string[] split = test.Split(' '); //Use empty space between word(s) as split character
for(int i=0; i< split.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(split[i]);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This yields 3 string elements in one-dimensional array, each element can be accessed via index. 0 = first word, **1 = second word**... so on.

Answer (score 4):

Why make it too complicated ? can do it simply by the following code     :

```
 string input = "kerry tells stories";
 string[] output=input.Split(' ');  
 textBox6.Text = output[0];
 textBox7.Text = output[1];
 textBox8.Text = output[2];
```

Comment: The same solution as presented by Joel but just a trifle easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is using the index of the first space, it doesn't move across.

> Reports the zero-based index of the **first occurrence** of the specified string in this instance.

You can do this much more simply by using [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var words = tbt.Split(new char[]{' '});
1 = words[0]
2 = words[1]
3 = words[2]
```

Comment: Note: Whilst you do you the correct override of `IndexOf` to work out the `indexnumber` variables, your substring calls do not

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using split with multiple tokens:

```
    Dim a() As String = txtSource.Text.Split({vbCr, vbLf, ".", "?", "!"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    txtSentences.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, a)
    a = txtSource.Text.Split({" ", ",", ";", ":", vbCr, vbLf, ".", "?", "!"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    txtWords.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, a)
```

Won't work with all cases, but a lot is them. Add three multiline textboxes to test: txtSource, txtSentences, TxtWords